# Fermentation before bottling

Tags: secondary-fermentation

I've today added the finnings. According to the instructions I should now leave it for another 2.5 days before bottling. What would happen if I leave it another 2 days longer?

Comment: Not much. :-) Relax, don't worry, have a homebrew...

Answer (score 5):

You are leaving the time for the finings to bind the yeast together and then giving them time to drop to the bottom of your FV. If you leave this a week longer all that will happen is the finings will sit at the bottom holding onto your yeast.

If you ever drop your beer into casks you can add finings and leave the cask sitting around for a month, the finings don't explode, taint the beer, etc....

Answer (score 1):

I did a 2 gallon batch of an American Wheat couple of months back with gelatin. Cold crashed for a week then added the gelatin put back in the fridge for another week, transferred to a keg chilled and carbonated for another week... came out beautiful and tasty.